# Downloaded Files Are Not Working on Apache DocumentRoot

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm serving my pages with Apache 2.4 on a Ubuntu Mate OS. I've been building a system that allows my clients to download many files from a directory which has been created by each one of them at the moment they sign in.

Apache DocumentRoot is **/var/www/public_html** and Downloads process works fine in it but by the time I create a folder CLIENTS (absolute path: **/var/www/public_html/CLIENTS/**) file downloads arent working as they should. There`s just a message saying "Failed - No File" on incoming files.

I've already changed Directory permissions with chown on Linux, changed masks as well as checked Apache configuration using *Directory* directives but no results! Apache settings below:

**VIRTUAL HOST CONFIGURATION**

`<Directory /var/www/public_html/CLIENTS/>
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>`

**APACHE2.CONF**

`<Directory /var/www/public_html/CLIENTS/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

**LINUX PERMISSIONS**

`drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data public_html`

Comment: What about the permissions of the files?

Comment: If you re talking about file/ group permission set by chmod, yeah... ive already did, my friend ! As shown above.